# Why Select distinct values with presto confilts with prestosql's implicit conversion

Tags: sql, trino

Case1:

```
Select distinct id, datetime 
from db 
where id = '1234567890123456789'
```

If I do this query in case1 while id's datatype is bigint, I get another result (the result is not in the database, so it's not a precision matter) which does not match my where clause , the result equals to `cast(cast(id as double) as bigint)`

If I switch to (without distinct)

Case2:

```
Select id, datetime 
from db 
where id = '1234567890123456789'
```

then we get the exact match.

I wonder if in case1, while querying, the implicit conversion in presto sql affects the raw data with distinct function (which will do cast twice), but without distinct , the only influence is the matching precision. This can recur if you select more than 2 values(not partition value) from presto environment.

Can anybody affirm my guess? Thanks!

Comment: The _best_ answer here is to only compare your `id` column against proper literals which are the same type as this column.

Comment: @Hill . . . I stop at "the result is not in the database".  This doesn't makes sense to me.  Something is clearly wrong if a query is returning data not in the database.

Comment: Thanks, I happened into this case. I know i need to compare with the same type, but i don't understand how the invalid result occurred with this situation which is the same as `cast(cast(id as double) as bigint)`